# How to set multiple value in custom dimension?

Tags: google-analytics

Our website is a blog site, and on each blog article, I'm trying to send "article category" as a custom dimension in Google Analytic.

I already set it successfully like this:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'category1');
```

but I wonder if an article has multiple categories, for example, an article may belongs to "News" and "Healthy", can I send both category to "dimension1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the values you want to dimension one.

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'news');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'cats');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'dogs');
```

Comment: Yes the second value is the name of the dimension the third value is the value you want to send to google analytics.  As long as the last value is a string you can send what ever you want.

Comment: I thought that dimension & its value was a 1 to 1 pair :P